# Why aren't my simple CSS margins collapsing?

Tags: html, web, margin, css

I've always heard that margins in CSS will collapse when next to each other, so that settings two elements to have 40px all around will only result in 40px between them.

Is this an old way to render CSS, as in does it not work this way anymore?

This is the HTML and CSS. I can't seem to get the margins to collapse:

```html
    <div id="header">
        <div id="mainNav" class="navBar">
            <a id="homeLink" class="navBarLinks">Home</a>
            <a id="aboutLink" class="navBarLinks">About</a>
            <a id="articlesLink" class="navBarLinks">Articles</a>
            <a id="portfolioLink" class="navBarLinks">Portfolio</a>
            <a id="contactLink" class="navBarLinks">Contact</a>
            <a id="rssLink" class="navBarLinks">RSS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="infoBar"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
    #header { width: 100% }
    .navBar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 24px;
        background-color: #1a1a1a;
        border: 0px solid #404040
    }
    #mainNav { border-bottom-width: 2px }
    .navBarLinks {
        display: block; float: left;
        height: 11px;
        margin: 0 30px;
        background: url(/images/STORMINKsprite.png) no-repeat;
        text-indent: -9999px
    }
```

Comment: What's up with that text-indent: -9999px? I'm curious.

Comment: The .navBarLinks are all replaced with sprites but I want the text to be there for accessibility and robots so I just indent it way off the page. I think that is standard? or am I using some archaic method?

Comment: me too.. this seems to be part of some larger html page...

Comment: @theIV - This is an image replacement technique known as the "Phark Method", and it's probably the most popular way of doing what Ian has in mind, at least for non-text image replacement.

Comment: Ah ok good to make sure I'm not using some outdated method. Also, should be noted that by non-text, I believe Anthony means non-bodytext or large passages.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your answer can be found in the [CSS2.1 specification recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> In CSS 2.1, horizontal margins never collapse.

So given the code you've written, you'll get 60px between each link - 30px for each element's margin.

What you probably want to do is use 15px horizontal margins, and then add 15px of horizontal padding to the containing element.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what currently happens on IE, but if you float two elements and have `margin-right: 30px;` on the first, and `margin-left: 30px;` on the second, there will be 60px between the two. So, I believe it doesn't collapse.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 elements with 40px margin on all 4 sides, then the gap between those two elements will be 80px.